# Python regex for matching next line if present

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have to match some lines as below.

*Case 1*:

```
[01:32:12.036,000] <tag> label: val3. STATUS = 0x1
[01:32:12.036,001] <tag> label: val3. MISC = 0x8
[02:58:34.971,000] <tag> label: val2. STATUS = 0x2
```

*Case 2*:

```
[01:32:12.036,000] <tag> label: val3. STATUS = 0x1
[02:58:34.971,000] <tag> label: val2. STATUS = 0x2
[01:32:12.036,001] <tag> label: val2. MISC = 0x6
```

The line that has `MISC` value is optional and may be missing. The line with `STATUS` will always preceed `MISC` line and is always present.

To match this I am using regex like this: `"label: val(\d+). STATUS = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)(.*?(label: val(\d+). MISC = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)))?"`

This is working for *Case 1* and is correctly reporting the values. The ootput for matched groups is as below:

```
MATCH 1
[0] 3
[1] 0x1
[2] 
[01:32:12.036,001] <tag> label: val3. MISC = 0x8
[3] label: val3. MISC = 0x8
[4] 3
[5] 0x8

MATCH 2
[0] 2
[1] 0x2
[2] 
[3] 
[4] 
[5]
```

But for *Case 2*, this is skipping second `STATUS` in line 2 as below:

```
Match 1
[0] 3
[1] 0x1
[2] 
[02:58:34.971,000] <tag> label: val2. STATUS = 0x2
[01:32:12.036,001] <tag> label: val2. MISC = 0x6
[3] label: val2. MISC = 0x6
[4] 2
[5] 0x6
```

I needed 2 matches here also, with first match not reporting `MISC`.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not just use `label: val\d+\. STATUS = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)` if you don't care about `MISC` line

Comment: I care about ```MISC```. But it may not be present always. As in above examples it's missing for one ```STATUS```

Comment: If it is optional then just don't match it.

Comment: What I mean is, in log it may or may not be present. If it's present it needs to be matched

Comment: You are expecting only 2 matches when it is present in first sample, that means you are ignoring that line altogether

Comment: I think you are using a regex and have the dot match a newline, see https://regex101.com/r/oVfLeM/1 and https://regex101.com/r/c6FR3K/1 What you could do it is disable that (maybe you are using `re.DOTALL`) and then use a newline instead like `label: val(\d+)\. STATUS = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)(?:\n.*(label: val(\d+)\. MISC = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)))?` See https://regex101.com/r/Jqyr07/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks a lot. It Works now :). Please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the dot matching a newline `re.DOTALL` or multiline `re.MULTILINE` flag, you can match STATUS and then optionally match MISC on the second line using a newline using an optional non capture group.

Note to escape the dot to match it literally, and if label is at the end and only a single occurrence, you don't have to use a non greedy dot.

```
label: val(\d+)\. STATUS = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)(?:\n.*(label: val(\d+)\. MISC = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsN4gG/1)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"label: val(\d+)\. STATUS = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)(?:\n.*(label: val(\d+)\. MISC = (0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)))?"

s = ("[01:32:12.036,000] <tag> label: val3. STATUS = 0x1\n"
            "[02:58:34.971,000] <tag> label: val2. STATUS = 0x2\n"
            "[01:32:12.036,001] <tag> label: val2. MISC = 0x6")

matches = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(matches)
```

Output

```
[
  ('3', '0x1', '', '', ''),
  ('2', '0x2', 'label: val2. MISC = 0x6', '2', '0x6')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *capture pattern*.
This will return a group for each of the values.

```
^\[(.+?)\] <(.+?)> (.+?): (.+?) (STATUS|MISC) .+0x(.+?)$
```

```
01:32:12.036,000, tag, label, val3., STATUS, 1
01:32:12.036,001, tag, label, val3., MISC, 8
02:58:34.971,000, tag, label, val2., STATUS, 2
01:32:12.036,000, tag, label, val3., STATUS, 1
02:58:34.971,000, tag, label, val2., STATUS, 2
01:32:12.036,001, tag, label, val2., MISC, 6
```

For refined values, try the following.
This excludes the *"0x"*, on the last value.

```
^\[.+?\] <.+?> .+?: val(.+?)\. (STATUS|MISC) .+0x(.+?)$
```

```
3, 1
3, 8
2, 2
3, 1
2, 2
2, 6
```